# Automator Apple Script to convert jpeg image

Tags: applescript, automator

I used below automator function to convert png image to jpeg in bulk. It worked fine and converted all images in folder at once. But quality of jpeg image is not full.

Image 1: Automator Functions
[image]

Image 2: Preview App shows quality of image. How can we do same in automator above function ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this functionality is just not available in that Action (weirdly). I would suggest using the "Run Shell Script" Action.

**[EDIT: I've replaced everything here with new graphic and thorough explanation.]**

Explanation:

**In the red box:**

These are the Actions. There are 5. There are 2 Run Shell Script Actions, one directly following the other.

**In the green box:**

These are the details for the Actions.

**1: Ask for Finder Items:**

> Type: Folders
>     Do NOT Allow Multiple Selection

**2: Get Folder Contents:**

> You may use "Repeat for each subfolder found" if you wish

**3: Run Shell Script:**

> Pass Input: as arguments

The script:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    sips -s format jpeg -s formatOptions 100 "$f" --out "${f%.png}.jpg";
    #rm "$f";
    echo "${f%.png}.jpg"
done
```

**4: Run Shell Script:**

> Pass Input: as arguments

The script:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    echo "$f" | grep .jpg
done
```

**5: Move Finder Items:**

> To: *[select your folder]*

NOTE: To be safe, I have commented out the "rm" line in the first Run Shell Script script (put a "#" in front of it) for testing. This is the line that deletes the PNG files. If everything works after testing, you can remove the "#".

[image]

Comment: I tried your code but not worked, here is file: https://app.box.com/s/7fa5q6redy93kkzwwjklzs2nazzf7fwz

Comment: As I stated, you would need to pass files only to the Run Shell Script action to get it to work. Also, you did not change the "Pass input" option to "as arguments" as the graphic shows. I advise you to make a new workflow and simplify it by removing all the preceding Actions and replacing them with: 1) Ask for Finder Items (Type: Folders, do **not** allow Multiple Selection); 2) Get Folder Contents ---> this last is followed by the Run Shell Script, exactly as is in the graphic (with Pass input set to "as arguments"). It works. (I'm adding new graphic for preceding actions).

Comment: Thanks, now jpeg is converted to 100 quality, but png image also moved to  output folder: https://app.box.com/s/rpgghdnj9pgwgw02w8c7w1p5m7veg5b8

Comment: Ok, @DustBin you now have a complete answer. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clear answer. Its working great. Saved lots of my time :)

Answer (score 1):

Hello you may have to install ImageMagick, since I am not sure you can write an AppleScript or something to make Preview use a better quality, and I can't finde any user preferences setting for quality in the user defaults database. It may exist, but I haven't found it.

Here is a link with some info on  [ImageMagick: Command-line Tools: Convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) I think your best choice is to use an execute unix script action, after having converted the paths from finder, or the folder from finder, and have a shell script inside the action, that performs the converstion with the desired quality for you.

**New** (for the case that it is impossible to make CRGreens solution to work, see comments below)

We will need to  have the folder where your images that are to be converted to along the way, so I suggest you put the AppleScript below into a "run applescript action" in a new workflow, then select the folder where the conversion occur in finder, before you run the workflow you just created, then hit "Cmd-V" in a new TextEdit document, so you have it for later.

```
 on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Finder"
        if selection is not {} then
            set theSel to selection as alias list
        end if
    end tell
    if theSel is not {} then
        set theFol to item 1 of theSel
        set the clipboard to "cd " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFol
    else
        beep
    end if

 end run
```

Save and close the Automator workflow, in case you'll need it on another occation.

Comment: please post command to convert all image in folder to jpeg with quality - best(12)

Comment: Have you tried to enter "which sips" in a terminal window, that is the easiest solution. if sips is already there, then that solution is the easiest to fix. Unless of course you have now installed ImageMagick

Comment: And first of all, you should set the do unix script action in  CRGreens workflow to take input as parameter (upper right corner), it is currentlly set to from stdin, and then it won't work. If that works, then you can change 80 in the shell script action of his, to 100, and you'll have max quality.

Comment: thanks, now image converted to high quality jpeg but not moved to final output folder https://app.box.com/s/rpgghdnj9pgwgw02w8c7w1p5m7veg5b8

Comment: @CRGreen I followed all 4 steps and it works and converts  high quality jpeg, but original png image is not deleted. Ok, please check tomorrow and help me to move converted jpeg to new folder.